# How to do audit when using Spring batch as ETL

Tags: mysql, spring-batch, etl

I have a requirement to use Spring Batch as ETL to migrate data from one set of tables in a **source database (MySQL)** to another set of tables in **destination database(MySQL)**. The schema in destination tables is different from schema in source table, so i'm using processor to transform the data to match the schema of destination.

I need to do this **migration block by block**, i.e., like set of records at once on demand (**Not all at once**).

I have few concerns to take care of.

1) Audit (Make sure all the data is migrated)

2) Rollback & Retry (In case of error)

3) Error handling

4) How to keep updated of the new data of source table while migration is happening (No downtime)

Below are my thoughts of the same.

I will generate a random ID that will be unique for each job (may be a **UUID for each job**), and then put it in destination table (column in every row) while migrating.

**1) Audit:** My thought is to keep a count of the records i'm reading and then compare it with the rows of the destination table, once the migration is done.

**2) Rollback & Retry:** If the record count doesn't match in audit check, i will delete all the rows with the **batch UUID**, and then initiate the batch job again.

**3) Error handling:** Not sure of what other cases i need to be aware of, So i'm thinking just to log the errors.

**4) Delta changes:** I'm thinking to run the batch job again and again to find for the changes (with created_at, updated_at column values) until 0 records are found.

I want to understand, if any of the above steps can be done it in more better way? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to spend some more time reviewing Spring Batch as it already takes care of most of these things for you.

You can already run a single Spring Batch job and set it to do the processing in chunks, the size of which you configure when you setup the job.

Auditing is already covered.  The batch tables (and the Spring Batch admin interface) will keep a counts of all the records read in and written for each job instance, as well as the failure count (it you configured it to suppress exceptions).

Spring batch jobs already have retry and auto recover logic based on the aforementioned tables that track how many of the input records had already completed.   This is not an option when using a database as an input source though.  You would need to find an option in your table setup to identify the records completed, and or use a uniqueness constraint to the destination database so it can not re-write duplicate records.   Another option could be to have your job's first step to be to read in records to a flat file, and then read from that file as a next step to process from.   This should let the Spring Batch auto recovery logic work when the job is restarted.

Error handling is already covered as well.   Any failure will stop the job so no data is lost.   It will roll back the data in the current chunk it is processing.  You can can set it to ignore (suppress) specific exceptions if there are specific failures you want it to keep running on.   You can also set specific numbers of the different which exceptions to allow.   And of course you could log failure details so you can lookup later.

As mentioned before you would need a value or trigger on your source query to identify which records you have processed.  Which will allow you to keep running the chunk queries to pickup new records.

Comment: That's a great answer!